# Añadir fecha a nombre de archivo de tipo TXT en PHP

Tags: php, php5, file, filewriter

Deseo agregar la fecha al nombre de un archivo cuando este se crea.
Por ejemplo si mi archivo se llama

```
Miarchivo.txt
```

Cuando se genere el archivo lo muestre de esta forma:

```
Miarchivo-2018-01-26.txt
Miarchivo-2018/01/26.txt
```

En PHP ya puedo hacer lo siguiente:

1.-Par sacar la fecha actual:

```
$fechaActual = date("d-m-Y");
```

2.-Para crear un archivo:

```
$archivo = "H:/Miarchivo-.txt";
```

3.-Para escribir sobre el archivo:

```
$handler = fopen($archivo, 'w');
```

Comment: Solo tienes que concatenar la fecha al nombre del archivo `$archivo = "H:/Miarchivo-$fechaActual.txt";`

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que lo que buscas es:

```
$fechaActual = date("d-m-Y");
$archivo = "H:/Miarchivo-" . $fechaActual . ".txt";
$handler = fopen($archivo, 'w');
```